# How to auto lock windows 10

Tags: windows-10

1.First I tried to set screensaver and screensaver time. It doesn't run at all.

2. Next I use secpol.msc and set appropriate parameter [make windows 10 lock automatically after a set amount of inactivity](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/make-windows-10-lock-automatically-after-a-set-amount-of-inactivity/). Then I check it in regedit - it is set
3. Then I found [how to change the windows 10 lock screen timeout](https://www.howtogeek.com/267893/how-to-change-the-windows-10-lock-screen-timeout/) - but still nothing happens after time I set.

No more ideas... My card is RTX 2060...

Windows 10 Pro.

Rebooted many times.

Comment: use the power saving settings for the monitor

Comment: Your first link is correct, there is no reason it won't work. Did you reboot?

Comment: @harrymc Many times...

Comment: @djdomi Please be more specific... I suppose I did it before, but now I try everything...

Comment: take alook here https://www.howtogeek.com/267893/how-to-change-the-windows-10-lock-screen-timeout/

Comment: If nothing works, perhaps there is a problem with Windows. I suggest to follow the advice in the [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) article, including the described DISM command.

Comment: @djdomi Done in step 3. Still no screensaver

Comment: @harrymc already done (in step 3). Not working.

Comment: @brzezina please edit the question to update the question and Situation, remind to reboot

Comment: @djdomi Step 3 is exactly what you suggest. It the same link!